# Copying data from variable cells and pasting to fixed cells in another spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I am looking to build a macro in excel 2013 which can do the following:

1. Copy data from individual cells in one spreadsheet (spreadsheet 1). The columns will never change but the rows will as it is a continually updated database of parts.
2. Paste this data from spreadsheet 1 into the respective cell in another spreadsheet (spreadsheet 2). The cell in spreadsheet 2 will never change.
3. Print out this document.
4. Repeat step 1-3 for the next line of data in spreadsheet 1.

Note: Ideally the macro would allow for a user to highlight the portion of data in spreadsheet 1 that they want to copy into spreadsheet 2. The macro would then print off a version of spreadsheet 2 applicable to each line item in spreadsheet 1.

I would welcome any advice anyone can give me.

Current Code:

```
Sub SOAutomator()
'
' SOAutomator Macro
'

'
Range("A4").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("A5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("C4").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("A7:D7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("D4").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("I5:K5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("E4").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("E5:G5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("F4").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("H5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut From:=1, To:=1, Copies:=1, Collate _
    :=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate

Range("A5").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("A5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("C5").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("A7:D7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("D5").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("I5:K5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("E5").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("E5:G5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("F5").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("H5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut From:=1, To:=1, Copies:=1, Collate _
    :=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate

Range("A6").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("A5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("C6").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("A7:D7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("D6").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("I5:K5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("E6").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("E5:G5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("F6").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("H5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut From:=1, To:=1, Copies:=1, Collate _
    :=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate

Range("A7").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("A5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("C7").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("A7:D7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("D7").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("I5:K5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("E7").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("E5:G5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("F7").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("H5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut From:=1, To:=1, Copies:=1, Collate _
    :=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate

Range("A8").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("A5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("C8").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("A7:D7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("D8").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("I5:K5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("E8").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("E5:G5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("F8").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("H5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut From:=1, To:=1, Copies:=1, Collate _
    :=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate

Range("A9").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("A5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("C9").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("A7:D7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("D9").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("I5:K5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("E9").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("E5:G5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("F9").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("H5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut From:=1, To:=1, Copies:=1, Collate _
    :=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate

Range("A10").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("A5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("C10").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("A7:D7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("D10").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("I5:K5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("E10").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("E5:G5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("F10").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("H5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut From:=1, To:=1, Copies:=1, Collate _
    :=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate

Range("A11").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("A5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("C11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("A7:D7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("D11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("I5:K5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("E11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("E5:G5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate
Range("F11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Activate
Range("H5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut From:=1, To:=1, Copies:=1, Collate _
    :=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
Windows("Shop Order Automator Macro.xlsm").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: I doubt you're going to find anyone here that will simply give you the code you need... Your best bet is to start off trying to do a bit of it yourself and post questions here as you find yourself getting stuck - We're here to help you get over stuck points / offer advice, not give code...

Comment: you could start by turning on the macro recorder, which will give you some code to play around with. It'll give you Select [worksheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464.aspx), select [cell or range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx), [copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760.aspx) and [paste](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821951.aspx), [pastespecial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx), [print](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821195.aspx) the document.

Comment: +1 for the great advices!

Comment: Thank you for both your comments. I have run the macro recorder in the past. Where I get stuck is in running a command which only processes the information highlighted when the macro is run? Is there a way to do this? Sorry for being vague, I am very new to VBA and I am just trying to write a piece of code that will help out a work colleague.

Comment: Okay I am making progress with this. I have thought of a work around which makes the macro slightly easier to write. Is it possible however, to end the sub if the macro encounters an empty cell? I have pasted the code I have so far into the main question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiles OK, but not tested...

```
Sub SOAutomator()

Dim shtTemplate As Worksheet
Dim shtMacro As Worksheet
Dim rw As Range


    'adjust sheet names as needed...
    Set shtTemplate = Workbooks("Job Sheet Templates.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")
    'assumes macro is in "macro" workbook
    Set shtMacro = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")     

    Set rw = shtMacro.Rows(4) 'start on row 4

    'run until hit an empty cell in the first column...
    Do While Len(rw.Cells(1).Value) > 0

        With rw
            .Cells(1).Copy shtTemplate.Range("A5")
            .Cells(3).Copy shtTemplate.Range("A7:D7")
            .Cells(4).Copy shtTemplate.Range("I5:K5")
            .Cells(5).Copy shtTemplate.Range("E5:G5")
            .Cells(6).Copy shtTemplate.Range("H5")
        End With

        shtTemplate.PrintOut From:=1, To:=1, Copies:=1, _
                     Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False

        Set rw = rw.Offset(1, 0) 'next row

    Loop

    ThisWorkbook.Activate

End Sub
```